# Write generic SQL for both SQL Server and Oracle for displaying dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, date, type-conversion

I do have to query SQL Server and Oracle DB for the same project.  The DBMS depends on the client, but the structure is exactly the same.

For example, I do want to output dates without the "00:00:00" part, which is heavy and useless in a long output.

Currently, I do have to edit the query each time:

```
SELECT col1, dated_requested_without_time, col3, col4, col5, *
FROM table
WHERE
    date_requested = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 120)
--  date_requested = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Is there a clever way to write it in a way that's executable in both environments without any editing needed?

The goal is to display and compare against **today's date** (YYYY-MM-DD)...

I did succeed to use concatenations like this

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(col1, ' '), col2), '.')
```

instead of the

```
col1 + ' ' + col2 + '.'      -- For SQL Server.
col1 || ' ' || col2 || '.'   -- For Oracle.
```

for example. Hoping the same for the above date query…

Any successful help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, every RDBMS has a different "flavour" of SQL. In this case you have T-SQL and PL\SQL for SQL Server and Oracle. There are ISO standards for SQL, however, none of the RDBMS fully comply with them, and often not on the same parts of the standards either. If you are dealing with 2 different RDBMS, then part of that is to expect to have to use different syntax for them. Unless suddenly all the providers agree to completely adhere to the ISO standards, that's never going to change (and even then, they would have (unique) custom functionality on top of the ISO standard SQL).

Comment: I know, thanks, but maybe something is possible like for the CONCAT usage -- where I've had to search, but that works, if you limit CONCAT to 2 arguments… Just hoping for some allowed syntax… if that's possible...

Comment: Instead of building formatted date/time strings in SQL, format data in the application presentation layer and the problem is solved.

Comment: Nope, that's for outputting in DBeaver or SQL Server Management Studio… Too wide columns, with useless info. Need to see more columns at once...

Comment: @user3341592 . . . If you have an application that runs on multiple different databases you need to provide an interface layer to facilitate your queries.  That would typically be user-defined functions, views, and supporting tables (such as a calendar table).

Comment: There is an app, with different views, and different restrictions. I'm using direct SQL queries to be able to see everything at once, for all users. And I do use the SQL querying tools for that, from Oracle and Microsoft. Not that weird, no?  But then I need to see 20 to 30 columns per table, and have restrictions on today's date for example, reason of my request here.

Comment: And I'd like my queries to be runnable in the production environment of the clients, without needing to define functions or procedures -- I may even have no right to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
select cast(current_timestamp as date)
```

?

Comment: Used the following test in both MS SQL Server and Oracle: `SELECT CONCAT(CAST(date_requested AS date), '.'), CONCAT(CAST(current_timestamp AS date), '.') FROM table`...

Comment: And that works perfectly in both -- for concatenation as string, for comparison, for dates in the DB, and for today's date. I did expect this. And you gave it to me!  Thanks a lot...